# How to get a table "saved" after INSERTING the first record and adding it to an ARRAY of objects?

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access-2007, ado

I have an empty table in access and add data with a SQL INSERT statement.There after I use a procedure to go through the table and use ADO to put all the values into an array of objects.

After debugging i can see that the procedure doesnt find any values in the table and says that the table is at EOF and doesnt extract any values out of the table.

However if i terminate my application (close the program) and run it again, it seems to have "inserted" and "saved" the table in access and then does find values in the table and extracs it with ADO, and inserts it into the array of objects.

somehow i need to het the access database "saved" through delphi

```
 //inserts the new(first and following) records  
 begin
  qryVote.Active := False;
  qryVote.SQL.Text := 'insert INTO tblkandidate ([Leerder nr],Van,Naam,geboortedatum,[id nr],geslag,[sel nr],debietpunte,voogklas,deelname,stemme) VALUES ("'+leerdernr+'","'+van+'","'+naam+'",#'+gebdatum+'#,"'+idnr+'","'+geslag+'","'+selnr+'",'+inttostr(debiete)+',"'+voogklas+'","'+booltostr(bsport)+'",'+inttostr(stemme)+') ';
  qryVote.ExecSQL; 
  qryVote.SQL.Text := 'select * from tblkandidate';
  qryVote.Active := true;

  KandidateNaSkik; //procedure that goes through the table and puts every record into the array of objects (see below foe precedure)
  showmessage('Jou pesoonlike data is gestoor');
end;

procedure Tfrmvote.KandidateNaSkik;
var
    leerdernr,naam,van,idnr,selnr,voogklas,gebdatum,geslag : STRING;
    stemme, debiete: integer;
    bsport, gestem : boolean;
begin

frmvote.ADOTableVotek.open;

 with dbgviewp.DataSource.DataSet do
 begin
   frmvote.ADOTableVotek.first;

   iaantkan :=0;

   while not frmvote.ADOTableVotek.EOF do    
   begin

   inc(iaantkan);
   leerdernr := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['LEERDER NR']; 
   van := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['VAN'];
   naam := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['NAAM'];
   gebdatum := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['geboortedatum'];
   idnr := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['id nr'];
   geslag := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['geslag'];
   selnr := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['sel nr'];
   debiete := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['debietpunte'];
   voogklas := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['voogklas'];
   bsport := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['deelname'];
   stemme := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['stemme'];
   gestem := frmvote.ADOTableVotek['gestem'];

   //the above variables get sent to the array below

   arrkandidaat[iaantkan] := tVerkiesing.create(leerdernr, van, naam, 
        gebdatum,idnr,geslag,selnr,debiete,voogklas,bsport,gestem,stemme);

   frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Next;
end;{while}

end;{with}

end;
```

Comment: which answer did you refer this to? you should `accept` it if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you insert a record via `qryVote.ExecSQL`, the `ADOTableVotek` dataset dose not "know" that a new record was added to the DB, so either you call:

```
frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Requery;
```

e.g.:

```
procedure Tfrmvote.KandidateNaSkik;
begin
  ...
  if not frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Active then
    frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Open
  else
    frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Requery;
  ...
end;
```

Or add the new record via `ADOTableVotek` itself like this:

```
 ADOTableVotek.Append; // add new record
 ADOTableVotek.FieldByName('Leerder nr').AsString := leerdernr;
 // ADOTableVotek.FieldByName('etc..')...
 // etc...
 ADOTableVotek.Post; // post new record to the DB
```

The changes will reflect imedeatlly into `ADOTableVotek` and in your `dbgviewp`.
This way the `ADOTableVotek` can be always active. You need to call `ADOTableVotek.Open` only once (or set `ADOTableVotek.Active := True`). And you don't need to fetch all records from your DB each time you insert a new record.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reflect the changes try closing and reopening the dataset, like so

```
frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Close;
frmvote.ADOTableVotek.Open;
```